# IE8 CSS @font-face IE8 - fonts are flashing

Tags: internet-explorer-8, icons, webfonts

I'm having a problem with my icon fonts. It works with any other browsers but not with IE8. Already tried bulletproof solutions but without success. The problem is with IE8.. when page is loading, I can see icons, but when page is fully loaded ( progress bar ) my icons disappear.

I'm using external links for my icons files, but I don't think that's the problem. You can see a test page: www.maky.nazwa.pl/new

Does anyone know what's causing this madness?

BTW. Generated by IcoMoon.io

Answer (score 0):

for all who will try to find the answer... this line fixed my problems..

```
<link id="base-css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?family=icomoon" />
```

style.css?family=nameOfFont